# Spring Data JPA error with one-to-one and mapsId

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-one

I have a parent with:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="engineering.drawingrevisions")
public class DrawingRevision implements DrawingRevisionInterface, Serializable {
    private int drawingRevisionID;
    private DrawingRevisionManufacturing manufacturing;

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_drawingrevisionid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Override
    public int getDrawingRevisionID() {
        return drawingRevisionID;
    }

    public void setDrawingRevisionID(int drawingRevisionID) {
        this.drawingRevisionID = drawingRevisionID;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="drawingRevision", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({View.DrawingRevisionView.class,View.DrawingView.class,View.RFQueueView.class})
    public DrawingRevisionManufacturing getManufacturing() {
        return manufacturing;
    }

    public void setManufacturing(DrawingRevisionManufacturing manufacturing) {
        if (manufacturing==null) {
            if (this.manufacturing!=null) {
                this.manufacturing.setDrawingRevision(null);
            }
        } else {
            manufacturing.setDrawingRevision(this);
        }
        this.manufacturing = manufacturing;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="engineering.drawingrevision_manufacturing")
public class DrawingRevisionManufacturing implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int drawingRevisionID;
    private DrawingRevision drawingRevision;

    public DrawingRevisionManufacturing() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="fk_drawingrevisionid")
    public int getDrawingRevisionID() {
        return drawingRevisionID;
    }

    public void setDrawingRevisionID(int drawingRevisionID) {
        this.drawingRevisionID = drawingRevisionID;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("drawingRevisionID")
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_drawingrevisionid")
    public DrawingRevision getDrawingRevision() {
        return drawingRevision;
    }

    public void setDrawingRevision(DrawingRevision drawingRevision) {
        this.drawingRevision = drawingRevision;
    }
}
```

The problem surfaces when I have a new DrawingRevision with drawingRevisionID = 0.  What I am expecting is that the DrawingRevisionManufacturing will update its ID properly based on the CascadeType.ALL.

In my service layer, I make sure that there is an association:

```
if (rev.getManufacturing().getDrawingRevisionID()==0) {
    rev.getManufacturing().setDrawingRevision(rev);
}
```

With this code, then I get a foreign key constraint violation because it tries to insert an entry in drawingrevision_manufacturing with a drawingRevisionID of 0 (which is no good).

If I change `setDrawingRevision()` to be

```
public void setDrawingRevision(DrawingRevision drawingRevision) {
    this.drawingRevision = drawingRevision;
    this.drawingRevisionID = drawingRevision.getDrawingRevisionID();
}
```

then I get a hibernate error that the identifier of an instance was altered from 0 to 10322 (or whatever number).

What am I missing that will allow me to successfully save a new DrawingRevision?

Answer (score 0):

In the DrawingRevisionManufacturing entity to add below code,

```
@OneToOne
@MapsId("drawingRevisionID")
@JoinColumn(name="fk_drawingrevisionid" ,referencedColumnName ="pk_drawingrevisionid")
public DrawingRevision getDrawingRevision() {
    return drawingRevision;
}
```

if any issue inform

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it did not work.  The problem is not that it can't find the right column name.  The problem is how it is handling a new item with an id of 0.